# Video Play/Pause on click issue?

Tags: javascript, html, video, click, playback

I am making a video website and so far I haven't styled it much yet so it's just videos on a blank page.

I have made it so that videos don't buffer until you click the thumbnail on the page. I added code to pause the video when you click it while it's playing and also play it again when it's clicked again.

I set it so the controls show on the HTML video but there's one problem. When you click on the video itself to pause it works fine, but when you click anything on the controls bar at the bottom it also pauses. And on top of that when you click the play/pause button on the actually control bar, the button pauses the video but it then instantly starts playing again because my function for playing when video is clicked fires.

How can I make it so the on click events don't work on the controls bar?

Another issue also is that when in fullscreen, the click on video to pause feature doesn't work at all. How do I fix that? I know that's quite a few questions in one post. Sorry :D

I looked everywhere and couldn't find answers. Heres my HTML and my JavaScript. The website is here: https://googledrive.com/host/0BxOngeQ9zGOeeHdlS3YyUFluVkk/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Project Bluebar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="javascript/vidloader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <noscript><h1>JavaScript is disabled! The page will not function properly.</h1><br><br></noscript>

    <div id="1"><br><br><img class="video" onclick="vidcl('media/1.mp4', 'media/1.png', '1', '480', '480', 'i1', 'media/1mo.png');" id="i1" onmouseover="thumbch('i1', 'media/1mo.png');" onmouseout="thumbak('i1', 'media/1.png');" src="media/1.png" width="480" height="480"></div>
    <div id="2"><br><br><img class="video" onclick="vidcl('media/2.mp4', 'media/2.png', '2', '640', '480', 'i2', 'media/2mo.png');" id="i2" onmouseover="thumbch('i2', 'media/2mo.png');" onmouseout="thumbak('i2', 'media/2.png');" src="media/2.png" width="640" height="480"></div>
    <div id="3"><br><br><img class="video" onclick="vidcl('media/3.mp4', 'media/3.png', '3', '360', '360', 'i3', 'media/3mo.png');" id="i3" onmouseover="thumbch('i3', 'media/3mo.png');" onmouseout="thumbak('i3', 'media/3.png');" src="media/3.png" width="360" height="360"></div>
    <div id="4"><br><br><img class="video" onclick="vidcl('media/4.mp4', 'media/4.png', '4', '400', '300', 'i4', 'media/4mo.png');" id="i4" onmouseover="thumbch('i4', 'media/4mo.png');" onmouseout="thumbak('i4', 'media/4.png');" src="media/4.png" width="400" height="300"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

and the JavaScript

```
var cs;
var no;

for(var x = 1; x < 5; x++){
    no = x.toString();
    cs = 'img' + no + ' = new Image(); img' + no + ".src = 'media/" + no + "mo.png';";
    eval(cs);
}

var video;
var imgm;
var vidm;
var idm = '';
var widm;
var heim;
var imidm;
var hovimm;

function cla(){
    video = document.getElementById('av');
    if(video.paused){
        video.play();
    }else{
        video.pause();
    }
};

function vidcl(vid, img, id, wid, hei, imid, hovim){
    if(idm !== ''){
        document.getElementById(idm).innerHTML = '<br><br><img class="video" onclick="' + "vidcl('" + vidm + "', '" + imgm + "', '" + idm + "', '" + widm + "', '" +heim + "', '" + imidm + "', '" + hovimm + "');" + '" id="' + imidm + '" onmouseover="thumbch(' + "'" + imidm + "', '" + hovimm + "');" + '" onmouseout="thumbak(' + "'" + imidm + "', '" + imgm + "');" + '" src="' + imgm + '" width="' + widm + '" height="' + heim + '">';
    }
    vidm = vid;
    imgm = img;
    idm = id;
    widm = wid;
    heim = hei;
    imidm = imid;
    hovimm = hovim;
    window.location.hash = id;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<br><br><video id="av" class="video" ondblclick="fs();" onclick="cla();" src="' + vid + '" width="' + wid + '" height="' + hei + '" autoplay loop controls>';
};

window.onkeydown = function(event){
    video = document.getElementById('av');
    if(event.keyCode === 32){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(video.paused){
            video.play();
        }else{
            video.pause();
        }
    }
};

function thumbch(id, ims){
    document.getElementById(id).src = ims;
};

function thumbak(id, ims){
    document.getElementById(id).src = ims;
};

function fs(){
    video = document.getElementById('av');
    if(video.requestFullScreen){
        video.requestFullScreen();
    }else if(video.msRequestFullScreen){
        video.msRequestFullScreen();
    }else if(video.mozRequestFullScreen){
        video.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }else if(video.webkitRequestFullScreen){
        video.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
};
```

Comment: Add the Demo Link please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I disabled the default video controls and the context menu so that they the controls can't be re-enabled through it and I made my own controls.